# Binding data to a listview and hiding a field

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the code below in the constructor of my .cs file of a page. I am able to pull
data without a problem

```
    void  InitData()
            {
                ArticlesService objArtServ = new ArticlesService();
                Task<List<ArticlesModel>> dataRetrieved =  objArtServ.GetValues("News");

                //Bind headlines and Id to listview but hide Id
                // datalist.itemsource =  ? 

            }
```

Here is the service that returns the data for me without any problem.

```
    public class ArticlesService
        {
            HttpClient client;

            public async Task<List<ArticlesModel>>  GetValues(string category){
                client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://testing-dev.com/Api/Articles/DefaultArticles/" + category);
                var articlesModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ArticlesModel>>(response);
                return articlesModel;
            }

        }
```

I have a grid on this main page and a list view which will list the headlines from my model and Id. The id will be hidden
and not displayed on the list. 
Here is the code below

```
     <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                        <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" Placeholder="Search" SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"/>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                <ListView x:Name="dataList"  BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <Label FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding HeadLines}"></Label>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Here is my model I am using

```
    public class ArticlesModel
        {
            public Int32 Id { get; set; }
            public string HeadLines { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }
        }
```

Questions

1. How do I bind only the HeadLines and Id to my listview such that my Id will be hidden but the headlines will show in the listview
2. On the click of each row in my listview, I want to be able to pass the associated Id so I can use the Id to query my list for other things.
   How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind the id if you're not displaying it.  The ItemSelected event will pass you the complete ArticlesModel object for the row that was tapped, and you can easily get the ID from the model.

```
dataList.ItemSelected += (s,e) {

  if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;

  // item will be a pointer to the selected ArticlesModel object
  var item = (ArticlesModel)e.SelectedItem;

  // then you can use item.Id or any other property on ArticlesModel
};
```

Comment: I need the id of the selected row.

Comment: How about my InitData method? How do I bind the returned data to my itemsource. datalist.itemsource = dataRetrieved throws an error

Comment: When I step through it, it says "The requested operation cannot be completed because the object has been garbage collected"

Comment: try assigning the ItemSource in the OnAppearing method

Comment: Error: cannot implicitly convert type system.threading.Tasks. Task<system.collections.Generic.List<Articles.Model.ArticlesModel>> to System.Collections.IEnumerable. "an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast)

Comment: make your GetValues method async, and read up on using async/await in C#

Comment: If you look at my code, you will see that it is async. public async Task<List<ArticlesModel>>  GetValues(string category)

Comment: are you using await when calling it?  dataList.ItemsSource = await GetValues();